# My function to convert dates leaves out the month

Tags: perl

I have a function and the string fed into it is a date in US format from Sybase. I'm simply trying to put it into numeric format so I can do a date comparison. For example, if I sent `Sep 12 2019` string as an argument, I would expect the output to be `9-12-2019`. However, `$mon` appears to be always empty. I tried using `chomp` on `$ms` in case it somehow had a CR on the end, but that made no difference.

```
sub rnumeric
{  my ($d) = @_; # The parameter fed to this function
   print "Date to convert is $d ";
   my $ms = substr $d, 0, 3;
   if ($ms eq "Jan") { my $mon = "1" };
   if ($ms eq "Feb") { my $mon = "2" };
   if ($ms eq "Mar") { my $mon = "3" };
   if ($ms eq "Apr") { my $mon = "4" };
   if ($ms eq "May") { my $mon = "5" };
   if ($ms eq "Jun") { my $mon = "6" };
   if ($ms eq "Jul") { my $mon = "7" };
   if ($ms eq "Aug") { my $mon = "8" };
   if ($ms eq "Sep") { my $mon = "9" };
   if ($ms eq "Oct") { my $mon = "10"};
   if ($ms eq "Nov") { my $mon = "11"};
   if ($ms eq "Dec") { my $mon = "12"};
   my $day = trim(substr $d, 4, 2);
   my $yr = substr $d, 7, 4;
   my $d = $mon."-".$day."-".$yr;
   return $d;
}
```

Edit - sample output from "Print" statements.

```
Item overdue Date to convert is Jan  9 2015 11:59:00:000PM Our due date is -9-2015

Item overdue Date to convert is Feb  6 2014 11:59:00:000PM Our due date is -6-2014

Item overdue Date to convert is Feb  6 2014 11:59:00:000PM Our due date is -6-2014

Item overdue Date to convert is Jan 12 2015 11:59:00:000PM Our due date is -12-2015

Item overdue Date to convert is Jan 12 2015 11:59:00:000PM Our due date is -12-2015

Item overdue Date to convert is Sep  8 2016 11:59:00:000PM Our due date is -8-2016

Item overdue Date to convert is Sep  8 2016 11:59:00:000PM Our due date is -8-2016

Item overdue Date to convert is Oct  4 2013 11:59:00:000PM Our due date is -4-2013
```

I got the `trim` function from a helpful post online-I've used it for a while and it does work, although the regular expression logic it uses is beyond me.

```
sub trim
{ my $s = shift; $s =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g; return $s };
```

Unfortunately I can't use `use strict` because I have to open the Sybase database with code provided by the host, who didn't use it, meaning that it throws up problems with their code that I can't fix.

Comment: What would a sample input look like? [Edit] the question and add some sample data. And you might also look into [Date::Parse](https://metacpan.org/pod/Date::Parse), maybe that can help you there.

Comment: "Unfortunately I can't use use strict..." --> can't you put their code in a module and import it in your own code (which could then use strict). You can even enable/disable locally strict in your code. I think you are asking the wrong question. The right question is: how can I use strict when interacting with a piece of code that I can't change and doesn't use strict?

Answer (score 3):

If you store the name to number mapping in a hash, you can simply lookup the number. Most of your code then disappears:

```
use v5.10;

print rnumeric( 'Sep 12 2019' );
sub rnumeric {
    state %Months = map { state $n = 1; $_ => $n++ } qw(
        Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec );
    my( $month_name, $day, $year ) = split /\s+/, $_[0];
    join '-', $Months{$month_name}, $day, $year;
    }
```

If you don't like that `map`, you can assign the numbers yourself:

```
use v5.10;

print rnumeric( 'Sep 12 2019' );
sub rnumeric {
    state %Months = qw(
        Jan 1 Feb 2 Mar 3 Apr 4  May 5  Jun 6
        Jul 7 Aug 8 Sep 9 Oct 10 Nov 11 Dec 12);
    my( $month_name, $day, $year ) = split /\s+/, $_[0];
    join '-', $Months{$month_name}, $day, $year;
    }
```

But, I'd rather let something else think about this. The [Time::Piece](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Piece) module from the Standard Library can do it. Give it a format to recognize and parse the date, then another format to put it back together:

```
use v5.10;
use Time::Piece;

print rnumeric( 'Sep 12 2019' );
sub rnumeric {
    Time::Piece
        ->strptime( $_[0], "%b %d %Y" )
        ->strftime( '%-m-%-d-%Y' )
    }
```

The format like `%-m` uses the hyphen to strip leading zeros. If you want the leading zeros, it would be just `%m`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `strict` and `warnings`.  These will show you where your mistakes are.  You need to scope your variables properly.  It is good that you declare variables with `my`, but you should only declare each variable once.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

print rnumeric('Sep 12 2019');
print "\n";

sub rnumeric
{  my ($d) = @_; # The parameter fed to this function
   print "Date to convert is $d ";
   my $ms = substr $d, 0, 3;
   my $mon;
   if ($ms eq "Jan") { $mon = "1" };
   if ($ms eq "Feb") { $mon = "2" };
   if ($ms eq "Mar") { $mon = "3" };
   if ($ms eq "Apr") { $mon = "4" };
   if ($ms eq "May") { $mon = "5" };
   if ($ms eq "Jun") { $mon = "6" };
   if ($ms eq "Jul") { $mon = "7" };
   if ($ms eq "Aug") { $mon = "8" };
   if ($ms eq "Sep") { $mon = "9" };
   if ($ms eq "Oct") { $mon = "10"};
   if ($ms eq "Nov") { $mon = "11"};
   if ($ms eq "Dec") { $mon = "12"};
   my $day = trim(substr $d, 4, 2);
   my $yr = substr $d, 7, 4;
   $d = $mon."-".$day."-".$yr;
   return $d;
}
```